# How to proceed script as soon as file dropped in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to run a script as soon as a file is dropped in the window. At the moment I need to press ENTER to proceed. Is there a better way to do it?

```
echo Please drag and drop the file here and press ENTER.
set /p file_dropped= %~1
echo file name: %file_dropped%
:: Ask user to enter his own file name
set /p given_name= Give a name to the file (i.e. myfile)
echo Given name: %given_name%
```

Comment: Whoa! I had no idea the cmd window supported drag and drop like that. Very cool. I'll be very surprised if anyone can solve your problem natively - you would have to modify the behavior of drag and drop.

Comment: I'm afraid all you can do is drag-n-drop a file directly onto your batch **file** in Explorer. The very idea of console disallows reading an input without submitting.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Let the user drop the file not in DOS window but on the shortcut icon. You can name it *Drop your File Here.lnk*, that launches *dropafile.cmd* (without `%1` in its target) in some other folder, and decorate it with some suggestive icon. The code of *dropafile.cmd* would be:

```
@echo off  
echo You have dropped here the:  
echo %1  
echo.  
set /p given_name= Give a name to the file (i.e. myfile)
```

`%1` is valid until end of this batch.

Yes, this is workaround but works in the manner you need.